# Most efficient way of knowing if two images are the same?

Tags: macos, algorithm, cocoa, uiimage, nsimage

Working in Cocoa right now. Just want an ultra simple image-same algorithm. Doesn't need to be perfect. Just needs to be good enough.

Comment: You will need to define 'same'. Are they the same if one is a PNG and the other a JPEG but that look the same? Are they the same if one is identical to the other but rotated? Or resized? Are they the same if a single pixel is different? Are they the same if one is slightly brighter than the other?

Comment: Simple-same. What ever may work best in favor of efficiency. I guess I am wondering if there is some kind of simple vague comparison method. Hypothetically: Not rotated. Same sizes. Maybe compression or slight pixel differences possible but likely to be identical anyway.

Comment: I guess part of me was wondering if there is some kind of simple checksum method, something that would catch most cases, but maybe not the exceptions, the weird ones

Comment: Then allow an error margin of 5% to 10% of the general magnitude of pixel values. If you want fast results, compare a (pseudo) random sampling of the images. This way you catch with high probability cases where the images are different. By exclusion, what passes the test is with high probability the same image.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but are you interested in minimising execution time so you can do more images per second, or just minimising programming effort initially? Are you happy to code something at length to do more images per second? And do you have a performance goal in mind, e.g. 60 images of 649x480 per second?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the MD5 (or other) hash is a very straight forward approach and probably quite efficiency. For example,

```
// Very nice NSData category with different 
// hashes at https://gist.github.com/0xced/986427
#import "NSData+CommonDigest.h"

NSImage *image1 = ...
NSImage *image2 = ...
NSData *image1MD5 = [[image1 TIFFRepresentation] md5];
NSData *image2MD5 = [[image2 TIFFRepresentation] md5];
if ([image1MD5 isEqualToData:image2MD5]) {
    // image are the same
} else {
    // image are different
}
```

This will **match exactly**, however, if you want to **match heuristically** then this is of course possible you will have to define some metrics by which you can compare images. For example, you could subdivide your image and calculate the average RGB values for the different quadrants; using this information as a fingerprint. If an image has been proportionally resized then this should give the same result. However, if the image has been cropped or resized disproportionately then your milage might vary. This problem is in general quite difficult as you will have to accept false-positives. The success will depend on how different your images are and what metrics you pick for their comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion, your mileage may vary.

Make a folder with around 10-100 of your images, or just do 10 screen grabs using Cmd+Shift+4 and drawing a box around an area of the screen. Then go to that folder and try the example below.

Get ImageMagick (available for free [here](http://www.imagemagick.org)) you can get the image statitics really easily, like this

```
convert *.png -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]" info:
```

and

```
convert *.png -format "%[fx:mean]" info:
```

Those will tell you the mean and stddev of all the images in the folder. My iMac can do around 10 images of 100-300kB each per second.

Another way to compare, may be to reduce the image to say 4x4 pixels and then difference them.

You can also generate statistics using ImageMagick, so to calculate the Mean Squared Error between two images a.pgn and b.png, you would do:

```
compare -metric MSE a.png b.png /dev/null
```

Other options are a normalised cross correlation (NCC) and absolute error count (AE). Have a look at the options on [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/) page.

Here are some examples. I start with a screen-grab as `a.png`, then doodled on it in blue a little and saved it as `b.png` and then splatted blue all over the right half and saved it as `c.png`.

[image: a.png]
[image: b.png]
[image: c.png]

Then I ran:

```
# Compare Mean Squared Error of a.png with b.png (discarding result to /dev/null)
compare -metric MSE a.png b.png /dev/null 
47.5718 (0.0007259)

# Compare Mean Squared Error of a.png with c.png
compare -metric MSE a.png c.png /dev/null 
11893.9 (0.181489)
```

Obviously `a.png` is miles more similar to `b.png` than to `c.png`.

Going back to the simple averages I mentioned at the beginning:

```
convert a.png -format "%[fx:mean]" info:
0.0595082

convert b.png -format "%[fx:mean]" info:
0.0600574

convert c.png -format "%[fx:mean]" info:
0.195744
```

Note that `b.png` is very close to `a.png`, but `c.png` is miles away.

If performance is important, consider caching the results in an alternate data streem/resource fork/database.

Also, all Macs (Powerbooks and iMacs) are multi-cored so consider running multiple threads to process images in parallel.

On a Mac you can also use SIPS ([here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) to get information about images. ImageMagick also has `identify` ([here)](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) which tells you image sizes and colourspaces etc.

Also, ImageMagick has C language bindings, so you can either use those, or use something like fork+exec or system() to use the command-line versions.

Comment: Did this help you? If so, please consider accepting my answer so I get a lovely big green tick. If not, please say what went wrong so I, and other folks, can help you further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the fastest way is to bail out if they're not the same. 
Do this by first checking file size and name and other simple metadata. 
After that, check the first and last N bytes are the same and maybe some N bytes somewhere in the middle. 
The more accurate way would be to check a hash value but that could take a long time for a large file. 
The more percentage of the hash value that matches, the closer you get to a definite match.

By ruling out simple non matches quickly you save time most of the time. 
You could also cache hash values in the background while doing other things. This helps much of the comparing go faster.

A byte by byte comparison is the only 100% accurate method but is also the slowest.